# PHP count not working properly

Tags: php

This only returns User doesn't exist.
Im guessing it is the count that is failing but it worked last night, but not sure why it isn't currently working, i have been playing with my code and making it look better but everything else is still functioning and sadly i do not have any back ups. this is basically for reputation on my websites and this is the php file that the add reputation links to, e.g you are on someones profile ([id number 5]) then when you want to give them a reputation you click a link that is reputation.php?good=5
Pastebin link
http://pastebin.com/HizC9hq2

Comment: Gimme teh codez? Please try to understand your problem first and then ask a specific question. SO is not your debugging squad team.

Comment: If you want any good reply, please elaborate and format your question properly. I almost gave up from reading it.

Comment: As i understand you use string type for ids in rep table and int type for ids in members table, is it right? Maybe it's not related to the problem.

Comment: You don't need to use [mysql_fetch_row](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) when you only want one cell value, you can use [mysql_result](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php). (In your case: _$c_iue = mysql_result( $count_ifuserexists , 0 , 0 );_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try altering this line

`if ($c_iue == 1) {`

to read

`if ($c_iu[0]==1) {`